# POST request not successfully sent over server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, afnetworking

I am making an app that sends a push notification after that the app shuts down. I am using AFNetworking for talking to my server. Here is my AFNetworking function.

```
-(void)sendPushNotification:(NSMutableDictionary *)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock{
    NSLog(@"%@%@",kAPIHost,kAPIPush);
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:kAPIPush parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData){
        //TODO: attach file if needed
    }];
    NSLog(@"Till here");
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        //success !
        NSLog(@"SUCCESSSS!");
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        //Failure
        NSLog(@"FAILUREE!");
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];
    NSLog(@"tille here 2");
    [operation start];
    NSLog(@"till here 3");
}
```

Then for sending the pushnotification I have the following code.

```
- (IBAction)changeEnglish:(id)sender {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSString *alertCancel = NSLocalizedString(@"Home_alertCancel", nil);
    NSString *message = @"  Do you wish to change the language? The application will shut down after this. Next up you can restart it again.";

    BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Change language" message:message];

    [alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:alertCancel block:nil];
    [alert setDestructiveButtonWithTitle:@"Ok" block:^{
        [self sendPush];
        exit(0);
    }];
}
-(void)sendPush{
    [[API sharedInstance]sendPushNotification:NULL onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
        //completion
        if(![json objectForKey:@"error"]){
            NSLog(@"notification send");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Cannot connect to the server");
        }
    }];

}
```

First of all, when I execute the pushnotification in my browser (enter the link in my browser en hit enter) it works fine. But when I want to execute in code. It gives the following log.

```
2012-12-12 13:44:43.695 doktersApp[666:907] http://linkexample/simplepush.php
2012-12-12 13:44:43.702 doktersApp[666:907] till here
2012-12-12 13:44:43.705 doktersApp[666:907] till here2
2012-12-12 13:44:43.706 doktersApp[666:907] till here3
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna do it on exit?
then the problem is that the request is asynchronous. the OS doesnt wait for it and kills the app and the operation doesnt finish but is killed right after you call start.

one solution is to wrap it in a backgroundTask and with that tell the ios that you need a bit more time after quit.

example:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //begin
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"expired");
    }];
    assert(identifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid);

    //this simulates a request
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //THIS is your completion handler
        NSLog(@"done");
        [application endBackgroundTask:identifier];
    });
}
```

in your concrete case: (this obviously untested, the above is tested)

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //begin
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"expired");
    }];
    assert(identifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid);

    [[API sharedInstance]sendPushNotification:NULL onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
        //completion
        if(![json objectForKey:@"error"]){
            NSLog(@"notification send");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Cannot connect to the server");
        }
        NSLog(@"done");
        [application endBackgroundTask:identifier];
    }];
}
```